# Requesting a New Registration Id and Creating a Tag for the Azure Notification Hub with NodeJs

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-notificationhub

How to get a new registration Id for the Azure Notification Hub with JavaScript (NodeJS) and how to create the tag afterwards? The tutorial provided by the Azure documentation misses this part - it sends to all devices (null).

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-nodejs-how-to-use-notification-hubs/

```
  var payload={
    alert: 'Hello!'
  };
  notificationHubService.apns.send(null, payload, function(error){
    if(!error){
    // notification sent
    }
  });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Notification Hub apns object also has a createNativeRegistration(token, tags, options, callback) function.

```
var token='abcd1234......'; // token from iOS device
var tags = ['mynewtag', 'myoldtag'];
notificationHubService.apns.createNativeRegistration(token, tags, {success:newRegistrationCompleteCallback, error:newRegistrationErrorCallback});
```

If you are using the npm you can read the [source for it](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/tree/master/lib/services/serviceBus/lib) since the documentation is pretty incomplete.

If you are using Mobile Services' Node.js backend, see also the [documentation for the built-in push apns object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj839711.aspx), which seems to be using the same library.

Comment: Eric, trying more, this call is working for me: **notificationHubService.apns.createNativeRegistration(token, tags, null, newRegistrationCompleteCallback);** Thank you very much for leading me to the right direction! It is working, but I am not sure if it is correct - I have the impression something is missing. In C# I create first a registration and afterwards the tag. For the next message, I check if the registration exists. In the source you linked to, I found the  corresponding JavaScript APIs. It would be nice if MS would provide a full example.

Comment: when i am using the above method for android notificationHubService.gcm.createNativeRegistration(token, tags, {success:newRegistrationCompleteCallback, error:newRegistrationErrorCallback}); Its throwing as newRegistrationCompleteCallback undefined